# How to switch list view for file names

Tags: macos, finder

I have multiple files which I would like to arrange and view in 2 ways. One with person name first and other with bank name first. Files as follows -
John AMEX application
Peter AMEX application
John Citibank application
Peter Citibank application

.... and so on with multiple banks and multiple people. ATM, I'm saving my files with person name first and then the bank name.

I would like to know is there a way to switch views to view them as bank name first/person name second and vice versa. Thank you!

Comment: What is the content of the files? Do you actually need them listed in different ways, or do you just need a method to get to a specific file? Might a database be more useful?

Comment: There is no native method to list files by 'second word'. That's a database function, exemplified by such as an address book which can list by first name or last name.